# Trying to align social media icons so they are centered perfectly in between separators

Tags: html, css, web, icons, alignment

I added new menu separators and now the alignment for my social media icons are all out of whack. I need them to be centered. Not sure why this happened or how it can be fixed. I tried adding some CSS but had no luck. My website is http://www.stephensengineering.com/stephens33/ any help is greatly appreciated! :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<title>Horizontal Navigation Bar w/Rollover Effect</title> 
<style type="text/css"> 
<!-- 

#navbar ul { 
  height: inherit;
  /* margin: 0; REMOVE THIS*/
  margin-bottom: 0; /* Suggested */
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: right; 
  background-color: #000; 
} 

/* Suggested for aesthetic reasons */
#navbar {
  background-color: #000;
}

#navbar ul li  {  
    display: inline-block; 
    padding: 10px 4px;
  height: inherit;
    border-left: 1px  #696969;
}

#navbar ul li a { 
     font-family: 'Montserrat';
    text-decoration: bold; 
    padding: .2em 1em; 
    color: #fff; 
    border-left:1px solid #696969
/*     background-color: #000;  */
    } 

#navbar ul li:hover { 
    background-color: #000; 
    } 
#navbar ul li:hover a { 
    color: #fff !important; 
    } 
#navbar { background-color: #000; }
    #navbar{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100000; /*To bring the navbar to the top of the stacking context*/
    width: 100%;
    }
    nav.stricky-fixed.fadeInDown.animated{

   top:40px; /*Since this element is already set as relative in the original code,
              the top property places the slideIn menu 40px (height of black nav menu)
              from the top of the page.*/

  }

.social-icon-wrapper:nth-child(3) a {
    border-right: 1px solid #696969;
}
    .social-icon-wrapper:hover {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
.social-icon {
  width: 15px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

 .submit-btn {
  background-color: green !important;
    padding: .2em 1em; 
    border-left:1px dashed #696969
  }
--> 
</style> 
</head> 
<body> 
<!--  -->
<div id="navbar"> 
  <ul class="container"> 
      <ul>
        <li  class="social-icon-wrapper" style="float:left"><a href="#about"><img class="social-icon" src="https://i.imgur.com/tonPA8V.png"></a></li><!--  --><li  class="social-icon-wrapper" style="float:left"><a href="#about"><img class="social-icon" src="https://i.imgur.com/fEvitJl.png"></a></li><!--  --><li  class="social-icon-wrapper" style="float:left"><a href="#about"><img class="social-icon" src="https://i.imgur.com/UiwMSrt.png"></a></li><!--  --><li><a href="mailto:project@stephensengineering.com">project@stephensengineering.com</a></li><!--  --><li><a href="tel:+18883000642">888-300-0642</a></li><!--  --><li><a href="http://www.stephensengineering.com/stephens33/stephens-university/">Stephens University</a></li><!--  --><li class="submit-btn" ><a href="http://www.stephensengineering.com/stephens33/submit-assignment/">Submit Assignment</a></li> 
      </ul>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the icons to appear centered, the distance between each border needs to be equidistant. The border is applied to the left edge of the padding of your `anchor` tag so there is 0.5em padding to the left of the icon, but your forgetting the padding around your `list` element which will add 4px between the icon and the subsequent border, resulting in 0.5em + 4px worth of padding to the right.

Check out your `#navbar ul li` and change the padding to `padding: 10px 0px` and you'll see it starts to adjust. This isn't the full solution, because I understand you want that padding for the next set of links in your navbar.

In your set up you need to account for the padding of the `anchor` tag, the padding of the list element, and the width of the of the border itself. It would be better to apply the border to the `navbar ul li` instead of the interior `anchor` element.